# Cocoa Binding to an optional property in swift

Tags: swift, option-type, cocoa-bindings

How do I setup cocoa bindings for properties that are of optional datatype?

I have an NSTableView that displays data from NSArrayController via key bindings, which in turn is managing objects for an array of [Properties] which are defined as:

```
    class Property: NSObject {
        var distance: CLLocationDistance    
        var ETA: TimeInterval?                
        var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D
        // other properties and methods here
    }
```

in MainViewController I define

```
    var properties: [Property] = []
    @IBOutlet var arrayController: NSArrayController!
```

where arrayController is bound to `properties` array,
`NSTableView` is bound to Array Controller (Controller Key = `arrangedObjects`)
and then individual `TableViewCells` bound to various properties of Table Cell View (model key path = `objectValue.distance`, etc)

The code compiles without any issues, but at runtime it crashes when it tries to load the table.  The issue is with the ETA column since `properties.ETA` is an optional. What is the proper way of dealing with this issue?    Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly.

Cocoa Bindings work through the Objective-C runtime, and ObjC has no way to represent Swift Optionals that aren't of object (aka class aka reference) type. (That is, you can access an `NSWindow?` from ObjC, or even an `AnyObject?`, but not an `Int?` or a `CGRect?` or a `TimeInterval?`.)

Your best bet here is probably to fall back to doing things the way you would in ObjC — make `ETA` a non-optional `TimeInterval`, and use some sentinel value (negative something-huge?) to represent cases where an ETA is not set. You can use value transformers to make sure such cases get represented appropriately in your UI.

Alternately, you could keep the optional property for use in Swift, and expose a second, computed property of non-optional type for use in bindings.

Comment: Thank you!   and makes total sense given the ObjC origins of cocoa bindings.   i went with the 2nd alternative (computed property) and it works.

Comment: The computed property road worked well for me too! Thanks!